# SQL Server 2008 Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have data in a SQL Server 2008 table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to pivot it to look like this:

[image]

Basically I want to group on ReadTime and Coater and then pivot on the DataType column. Could someone help me with the T-SQL to do this?

Comment: Do you really want me to clutter this question with all the iterations of queries I've tried? That would only server to show you that I've actually tried something.

Comment: How about the most successful one?

Comment: @Hosea146 actually by showing the queries you have tried it helps the community see if changing what you have done will give you the desired result. So it isn't a waste of time on both sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ReadTime DATETIME,
    Coater VARCHAR(100),
    Value FLOAT,
    DateType VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11A-COATER',1,'FCDAOpside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11A-COATER',1,'FCDABackside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11A-COATER',0,'FCDAOpside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11A-COATER',0.9,'FCDABackside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11B-COATER',1,'FCDAOpside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11B-COATER',2,'FCDABackside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11B-COATER',2.9,'FCDAOpside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:01','PBG11B-COATER',0,'FCDABackside473')

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11A-COATER',1,'FCDAOpside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11A-COATER',1,'FCDABackside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11A-COATER',0,'FCDAOpside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11A-COATER',0.9,'FCDABackside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11B-COATER',1,'FCDAOpside473')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11B-COATER',2,'FCDABackside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11B-COATER',2.9,'FCDAOpside472')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2012-10-01 13:28:41','PBG11B-COATER',0,'FCDABackside473')
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ReadTime,
        Coater, 
        DateType,
        Value
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
        MIN(Value)
        FOR DateType IN 
                     (
                        [FCDAOpside472], 
                        [FCDAOpside473], 
                        [FCDABackside472], 
                        [FCDABackside473]
                     )
    )AS PivotTable
 ORDER BY 
    ReadTime
```